# View overlaps status bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios8, statusbar, overlap

Is it possible to make a view overlap the status bar like the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the window level of the current view controller "above" the status bar like this:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1];
```

Comment: this is exactly the idea but all I can see is the whole status bar hidden

Comment: Are you sure the view is not covering the whole status bar?

Comment: You may need to set the view controller background to transparent.

Comment: is the idea in itself that make no sense

Comment: @elio.d I don't understand what you're trying to say.